# First Error: Duplicate Field Selected

Tags: apex, batch, error

What could be the possible reasons of this Error Message.

I have written one Batch Class -
I first got CAN_NOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD and then above error

Now I have update my Query   `...... From LEAD where isConverted !=True"`

I want to be sure that now I should not face any errors.

I have following screenshot for more referance

[image]

Comment: As the error `Duplicate Field Selected: LastName` suggests, you have `LastName` listed twice in your SOQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As BarCotter said you must have the LastName field in the batche's SOQL query twice or more.

So you might have something like this:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext info) { 

    String q = 'SELECT Id';
    q += ' ,Name';
    q += ' ,OwnerId';
    q += ' ,LastName';
    q += ' ,FirstName';
    q += ' ,LastName';
    q += ' FROM Lead';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(q);
}
```

Which you would need to change to this (i.e. remove the second reference to the LastName field):

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext info) { 

    String q = 'SELECT Id';
    q += ' ,Name';
    q += ' ,OwnerId';
    q += ' ,LastName';
    q += ' ,FirstName';
    q += ' FROM Lead';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(q);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How does this not answer the question "What could be the possible reasons of this Error Message." - the reason is "you must have the LastName field in the batche's SOQL query twice or more."

Comment: While writing an answer you better give some more useful and detailed  information, code examples etc. At the moment it is more a comment as an answer.

Comment: Ok ok :) How about that?

Answer (score 2):

This is where sets come in handy:

```
Set<String> uniqueFields = new Set<String>
{
    'LastName', 'FirstName',
    'LastName', 'Name',
    'OwnerId', 'LastName'
};
String fieldsToQuery = String.join(new List<String> ( uniqueFields ), ', ');
```